What is the Hoop stress and bending moment relation
So I am working on a club telescope project. I have to design the tube for the telescope.
So I found hoop stress to be most critical stress.
The tube's bottommost end has a mirror and a mirror cell. I considered the tube weight to be uniformly distributed along the length and a dovetail(connects the telescope tube to the telescope mount) is acting as a support.
I drew the shear force and bending moment diagram.
I also found the axial stress, but I am struggling to find the hoop stress as the weight is varying along the lenght.
I read in one paper that hoop stress is related to bending moment.
I need help in finding the hoop stress, I tried making an integral to find the hoop stress but failed.
Please help me in how to approach this. (There is no internal pressure)

How did you find that hoop stress is the most critical? If you were concerned about hoop stress caused by (differential) internal pressure, which is zero, then the hoop stress is also zero.

My professor told me to consider Hoop stress, about the critical part I wrote it by mistake.

Your professor is right in the sense that generally you should consider hoop stress, but that does not mean hoop stress will always be significant.
